# Computing volume of intersection of two regions

Tags: regions, finite-element-method, mesh, crash, discretization

I am trying to compute the volume of intersection of the following two regions:

```
a = 0.857597;
b = 1.653926;
hexagon = Polygon[{{0, (b - a)/2, 1/2}, {(b - a)/2, 0, 1/2},
    {1/2, 0, (b - 1)/(2 a)}, {1/2, (b - 1)/2, 0}, {(b - 1)/2, 1/2, 0},
    {0, 1/2, (b - 1)/(2 a)}}];
octahedron = ImplicitRegion[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + a Abs[z] <= b/2, {x, y, z}];
region2 = ImplicitRegion[1 >= RegionDistance[hexagon, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}];
```

`NIntegrate` directly doesn't work:

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ RegionIntersection[octahedron, region2]]
```

It results in a crash after using up the memory (32GB).

I tried to use `DiscretizeRegion` first:

```
octd = DiscretizeRegion[octahedron, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
regd = DiscretizeRegion[region2, {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}]; (* This takes 40 minutes *)
RegionIntersection[octd, regd]
```

This returns an error: “BoundaryMeshRegion: The boundary surface is not closed because the edges <<2>> only come from a single face.”

I also tried to discretize the regions using `` NDSolve`FEM`ToElementMesh ``.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
ToElementMesh[region2, {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}]
```

This crashes without using significant memory. Computing finite element mesh on the first region does not crash, but intersecting it with the second region results in a crash without significant memory usage.

```
octf = ToElementMesh[octahedron, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
RegionIntersection[octf, regd]
```

I have reported the issues with `ToElementMesh` to Wolfram Support.

Is there any workaround?

```
$Version (* 12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 18, 2020) *)
```

Comment: @MarcoB the intersection is not with the hexagon, but it's with `region2`, a blob around the hexagon where all points in the region are within distance 1 from the hexagon. You can visualize it here: `RegionPlot3D[
 1 >= RegionDistance[hexagon, {x, y, z}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 
  2}, {z, -2, 2}]`

Comment: @flinty Ah! You're right. Deleting previous comment.

Comment: Just so you know, this is still broken in v12.1.1 and continues to crash the kernel :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach based on creating exact regions:

```
a = Rationalize[0.857597, 10^-16];
b = Rationalize[1.653926, 10^-16];
hexagon = 
  Polygon[{{0, (b - a)/2, 1/2}, {(b - a)/2, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 
      0, (b - 1)/(2 a)}, {1/2, (b - 1)/2, 0}, {(b - 1)/2, 1/2, 0}, {0,
       1/2, (b - 1)/(2 a)}}] // Simplify;
octahedron = 
  ImplicitRegion[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + a Abs[z] <= b/2, {x, y, z}];
rd = RegionDistance[hexagon, {x, y, z}];
region2 = ImplicitRegion[1 >= rd, {x, y, z}];
ri = RegionIntersection[octahedron, region2];
```

This will run for a few seconds but will return an exact region that we then can mesh.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bounds = {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}};
mesh = ToElementMesh[ri, bounds, 
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", 
     "SamplePoints" -> {15, 15, 31}}];
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm[Green]]]
```

[image]

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh]
0.871456
```

I have also tried to make use of the [OpenCasadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html) based on the approach given by @flinty.

```
hexcenter = RegionCentroid[hexagon];
hexnormal = 
  Normalize[
   Cross[hexagon[[1, 1]] - hexcenter, hexagon[[1, 2]] - hexcenter]];
hexradius = Norm[hexcenter - hexagon[[1, 1]]];
cylinderhack = 
  Cylinder[{hexcenter - hexnormal, hexcenter + hexnormal}, 
   hexradius];
hexhack = 
  Flatten[{MeshPrimitives[hexagon, 1] /. Line -> Cylinder, 
    MeshPrimitives[hexagon, 0] /. Point -> Ball, cylinderhack}];
```

Load the link and convert the primitives into open cascade shapes:

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
shapes = OpenCascadeShape /@ hexhack;
union = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[shapes];
oocOcta = OpenCascadeShape[ToBoundaryMesh[octahedron]];
res = OpenCascadeShapeIntersection[union, oocOcta];
```

If you have a better representation of the octahedron, then we'd not need to convert to a boundary element mesh that is then converted to open cascade.

Get the boundary element mesh:

```
bmesh2 = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[res];
```

However, when we look at the `MeshRegion` version of the boundary element mesh we will see that there is a very slight elevation at the intersection - it's very hard to see at the top left corner:

```
MeshRegion[bmesh2]
```

[image]

And that can not be meshed with `ToElementMesh` - which is not ideal but understandable.

---

**Edit by @YizhenChen:**

The following representation of the octahedron gives more accurate answers:

```
octahedron = ConvexHullMesh[{{b/2, 0, 0}, {-b/2, 0, 0}, {0, b/2, 0},
  {0, -b/2, 0}, {0, 0, b/(2 a)}, {0, 0, -b/(2 a)}}];
```

The `cylinderhack` given by @flinty is also incorrect, because it results in the "very slight elevation" seen in the figure above. The correct one is:

```
cylinderhack =
  Apply[Prism[{hexagon[[1, #1]] + hexnormal, 
      hexagon[[1, #2]] + hexnormal, hexagon[[1, #3]] + hexnormal, 
      hexagon[[1, #1]] - hexnormal, hexagon[[1, #2]] - hexnormal, 
      hexagon[[1, #3]] - hexnormal}] &, #] & /@ {{1, 2, 3},
    {1, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 5, 6}};
```

Comment: Thank you. I can replicate the result. However, now I worry about the efficiency of computing the exact region, as in my actual project (not included in the question) I need to compute volume of intersection of more complicated regions. I will try similar techniques on my project (with lower precision), and I hope there could be a more numerical approach, in case the computation requires too much memory.

Comment: @YizhenChen, I think you best bet is to try to make use of the open cascade link as much as possible, as that will create very good regions efficiently.

Comment: Unfortunately open cascade link may not work. For example, the volume of the octahedron is `NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] octahedron]`, which gives 0.879253. But `NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] MeshRegion@OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh@OpenCascadeShape@ToBoundaryMesh@octahedron]` gives the incorrect result 5.20195.

Comment: The number 5.20195 is actually the surface area. To get the volume I tried `NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] MeshRegion@ToElementMesh@OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh@OpenCascadeShape@ToElementMesh@octahedron]`. This gives the incorrect result 0.874412.

Comment: @YizhenChen What are the expected surface area and the expected volume for the octahedron?

Comment: The expected volume is 0.879253 and the expected surface area is 5.27552

Comment: Now I have figured it out. `MeshRegion@ToElementMesh@octahedron` outputs something different from the octahedron; it is a smaller polyhedron with 12 faces, hence the volume and surface area are different. To get the octahedron I shouldn't use `ImplicitRegion`. The octahedron represented as the convex hull of the vertices gives the correct volume and surface area. I will edit your answer to include the correct representations.

Comment: @YizhenChen, yes please edit. Sounds good!

Answer (score 6):

This is not ideal, but it gives an approximate resulting region. I first generate random points on the hexagon and add a random vector on the unit sphere. I take the convex hull of the points which is acceptable because the blob must be convex. Finally I discretize the octahedron and intersect with `crudehexagonblob`:

```
crudehexagonblob = 
  ConvexHullMesh[# + RandomPoint[Sphere[#, 1]] & /@ 
    RandomPoint[hexagon, 40000]];
RegionIntersection[DiscretizeRegion[octahedron], crudehexagonblob]
```

Sadly convex hull is buggy and if I do 50000 or 20000 points I get an empty region, so I did 40000 and it worked. What a mess.

You could find a way to represent `region2` differently. I'm thinking you can put spheres at all vertices and cylinders along all edges and join it to a cylinder at the center. I think this combination of spheres and cylinders is identical to `region2`:

```
RegionPlot3D[1 >= RegionDistance[hexagon, {x, y, z}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]

hexcenter = RegionCentroid[hexagon];
hexnormal = Normalize[Cross[hexagon[[1, 1]] - hexcenter, hexagon[[1, 2]] - hexcenter]];
hexradius = Norm[hexcenter - hexagon[[1, 1]]];
cylinderhack = Cylinder[{hexcenter - hexnormal, hexcenter + hexnormal}, hexradius];
hexhack = Flatten[{
    MeshPrimitives[hexagon, 1] /. Line -> Cylinder,
    MeshPrimitives[hexagon, 0] /. Point -> Ball,
    cylinderhack}];
Graphics3D[hexhack]
```

[image: hexagon blob plots]

Unfortunately I had to use the same hack with `ConvexHullMesh` and random points to get a mesh out of the `RegionUnion` of these combined cylinders and spheres, because if you discretize them individually and `RegionUnion` them together it fails. Still, this mesh is pretty good:

```
cvxhm = ConvexHullMesh[RandomPoint[RegionUnion[RegionBoundary /@ hexhack], 40000]]
```

[image: approx mesh blob hexagon]

And disappointingly we can't even intersect this with the octahedron! I welcome any advice to get this to work:

```
(* unfortunately this fails for me in v12.1 *)
RegionIntersection[
 DiscretizeRegion@octahedron,
 cvxhm
]
```

Even though it doesn't provide a satisfying answer, I hope I've provided something you or somebody else can build on.

Comment: "What a mess." That are the right words to describe this!